# mysql command line help (windows)

Tags: mysql, command-line

i'm trying to do some practices on command line..

[image]

as you see in the pic the command is not triggering. i'm pressing  Enter. (as described in practicing book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End a command with a semicolon `;`

```
CREATE DATABASE deneme;
```

As long as it keeps printing the `->` prompt on new lines, it is expecting the `;` terminator.

Comment: thank you. i got it now. so in this pic mysql is waiting for more commands until ; right?

Comment: @micheal, i am trying to connect but getting this error:

mysql> -uroot;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-uroo
t' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 1):

Use `;` as stated.

This is a good example of why it is good practice to always end your SQL statements with a semicolon. It's a good habit to get into.

Comment: +1 many clients don't require the `;` but it is an excellent habit.

Comment: i am trying to connect but getting this error: mysql> -uroot; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-uroo t' at line 1 mysql> –

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the mysql client while you're already in it?

Answer (score 0):

just type

```
;
```

at the end of the line
:-)